# Can't initialize platform using node.js and io.js

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, io.js

I'm trying to implement V8 scripting.  I get this: error C2039: 'Platform' : is not a member of 'node'

This line concerned is:

```
V8::InitializePlatform(new node::Platform(4));
```

In my Interface.cpp, taken from https://github.com/iojs/io.js/blob/v1.x/src/node.cc#L3638. If I add this line:

```
#include <node_v8_platform.h>
```

I get:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall node::Platform::Platform(unsigned int)" (??0Platform@node@@QAE@I@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Scribe::V8Interface::initialize(void)" (?initialize@V8Interface@Scribe@@QAEXXZ)
```

Any idea?

i have Windows 7 x64 but I'm compiling for x86. Since io.js was made an executable, I needed to follow these instructions https://github.com/iojs/io.js/issues/537#issuecomment-70824398

Note that directly using node::Start worked.

I linked libuv, and some things like that. There is a folder in build/Debug where there are the v8 libs, but the main ouput folder only contains a small iojs.lib which I linked (too small to contains whole v8) and a 15 Mb iojs.dll which I copied to the folder where there is my exe

Comment: Please include your OS, its version and processor architecture. I believe you will get better help if you ask this in the respective project's github page.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/440558

Comment: Done! @JoachimPileborg  I know what it means, but don't know what to do in my case

Comment: There must be a library that you must *link* with.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg there are v8.lib and so on which I did not linked, but when using node::Start I did not needed them

Comment: Some functionality is implemented in header files, some are not.

Comment: Yeah, but why node::Start works whereas almost copying node::Start in my code doesn't?